# Querying for a specific value at the intersection of a Row and a Column in a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have a DataTable (myDatable) whose first line is a row of headers and whose subsequent rows are simply numerical data. For example:

```
    | WaterPercent | Ethylene | Toluene |
    |1.0312345     | 74.1323  | 234.000 |
    |56.054657     | 18.6540  | 234.000 |
    |37.57000      | 94.6540  | 425.000 |
```

At this point, all of its data contained within its `myDataTable.Columns` and `myDataTable.Rows` are `Strings`.

using this query:

```
var results = from row in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
              select row.Field<string>("Ethylene");
```

I can get all of the values in the Ethylene column, but I want to filter my query with a "where" clause such that I can retrieve just one value at the intersection of a specific row index and a column like "Ethylene".

Consequently it doesn't look like (unless I am missing something) that i can get access to the index of the rows collection using '`row`' in a Linq query. Even if I had this, I am not sure how to form the "where" clause of my query to get what I want.

What do I need for my query to be able to filter the result down to the intersection of a specific row and a column?

For example I want the value 18.6540 which exists at the row index of 2 and the column of Ethylene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the specific row index, then you can specify row index directly using `.Rows` collection, like you would index an array or collection (since it's 0-based indexing, row 2 would be index `1`):

```
var result = myDataTable.Rows[1].Field<String>("Ethylene")
```

Comment: Oh wow. That's a lot simpler than I had imagined. Why don't I have to "adorn" `myDataTable` with `AsEnumerable()` (as I have in my example above)?

Comment: @IsaiahNelson: Because in my example, I'm not even using LINQ (it's not necessary in this case).  If you want to select just the field *first* using LINQ, and then grab the 2nd entry, you can use `bnieland`'s solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you do not do it in the result?

```
var results = (from row in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
          select row.Field<string>("Ethylene")).ToArray();
```

then just index

```
var myVal = results[2];
```

Otherwise, you will want to use Skip() and Take().

```
String result = (from row in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
              select row.Field<string>("Ethylene")).Skip(2).Take(1).Single();
```

Comment: You also bring up a good point. I could simply do it in the result. I prefer to go for the most succinct solution but your's is one I certainly hadnt even thought of. +1.